# Unix commands to overrun OS X Finder shortcut cmd-opt-esc

Tags: keyboard, finder, command-line

I need to temporarily block the sequence <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>opt</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd>: I developed a formal examination test app for my students, and I need them to not get out of the test other than clicking a button in the test window.

BetterTouchTool accepts any shortcut except that (it seems to me, but I might make mistakes) I tried any combination, but always the forced quit window appears, as well as it happens in System Preferences > Keyboard > etc as suggested in "MacBook Pro, Yosemite: change Finder shortcuts".

I run Yosemite 10.10.5 and intend to stay with it until further upgrades will keep my Adobe suite working.

Answer (score 1):

To get this to work you have to use a third party tool: Karabiner.

In the example below the key combination <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>opt</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd> darkens the monitor.

1. Download, install and open [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)
2. Open in the menulet Karabiner -> Preferences
3. Open the tab *Misc & Uninstall*
4. Hit the button <kbd>Open private.xml</kbd>
5. Open the file private.xml with an appropriate editor
6. Enter the customized keycode

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <root>
       <item>
           <name>Disable Command Option Escape</name>
           <identifier>disable_cmd_alt_esc</identifier>
           <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::ESCAPE, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_OPTION, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_COMMAND, ConsumerKeyCode::BRIGHTNESS_DOWN</autogen>
      </item>
   </root>
   ```
7. Save the file
8. Open in the menulet Karabiner -> Preferences the tab *Change Key*
9. Hit the ReloadXML button
10. Enable the remapping. It should be listed at the beginning.

---

You may refine the customized key code by adding a shortcut to brighten the monitor again to avoid a totally darkened screen and a helpless student sitting in front of it - unable to continue the test:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <item>
        <name>Disable Command Option Escape</name>
        <identifier>disable_cmd_alt_esc</identifier>
        <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::ESCAPE, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_OPTION, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L, ConsumerKeyCode::BRIGHTNESS_DOWN</autogen>
        <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::ESCAPE, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_OPTION, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_R, ConsumerKeyCode::BRIGHTNESS_UP</autogen>
   </item>
</root>
```

In the first configuration each key combination (<kbd>cmd_l/r</kbd><kbd>alt_l/r</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd>) darkens the screen. In the second configuration <kbd>cmd_l</kbd><kbd>alt_l/r</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd> darkens and <kbd>cmd_r</kbd><kbd>alt_l/r</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd> brightens the screen.

*Karabiner* also allows you to [define application](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en#appdef-steps)-only key codes. By adding your app to /Applications/Karabiner.app/Contents/Resources/appdef.xml or to private.xml you can restrict the customized key code to your app's realm. Below the `<identifier>` tag you have to add a line `<only>Your_App's_Name</only>` then.

---

Depending on your app you probably have to disable some other shortcuts too: e.g. <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>. Additionally you may have to hide Karabiner in the menubar.

Comment: Tank you so much! I'll try ASAP! cmd-Q and others (like screen saver commands, in order not to have the questions copied and diffused on socials...) are already intercepted, but cmd-opt-escape was a stone wall... thank you again

Comment: Works like magic!

Comment: One more problem though, but i think I'll be able to solve it: the apple option force quit is still available, but I'll remove the menu and use a document window. Or Karabiner can disable that as well? Thanks anyway. MC

Comment: @user185912 You can disable the shortcut with Karabiner. To remove the shortcut completely you have to hack the (AKAIK) Finder.app

Comment: @user185912 Hmm just checked Karabiner again. Power Button support removed since 10.9. It may still be possible to disable a short cut containing the power button with Karabiner. This is the power button: ⎋ isn't it?

Comment: @klanomath No, that’s Escape.